# multisite: only changing name of the website

Tags: 7, multi-sites

I have a multisite up and running, which has completely different domain names but absolutely the same content (I'm using filters to filter the content by domain).

Everything works splendid with almost no redundancy. However, the only thing keeping me from rejoicing, is that I cannot change the name of the website domain-wise.

So basically, my question is where I can set this up, or rather:
Is there a way to override the page's name on drupal load?
And if there's not, can anyone tell me which table the site's name is getting stored, so I can domain-prefix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a settings.php file per site ?

If yes, you can add inside `$conf['site_title'] = 'My Site name'` this variable his stocked in the table `variable`but you can override it directly with settings.php.